# Microsoft Graph - Skype for Business reporting

Tags: powershell, microsoft-graph-api, skype-for-business

I created a thread which can be found here -- [Error 400 Bad Request when attempting to pull Skype for Business activity via Graph API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43394129/error-400-bad-request-when-attempting-to-pull-skype-for-business-activity-via-gr)

The Microsoft Graph support site points you here for questions such as these.

Can someone at Microsoft please provide some kind of input on when Microsoft Graph or PowerShell will have access to retrieve Skype for Business PSTN call \ activity details?

The Graph Beta API is functioning now but it still doesn't return PSTN call data.

Using the reports GUI in the SfB console of Office 365 doesn't have the functionality we need.

Please let me know if I'm missing some documentation about how to obtain these statistics in an automated fashion?

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow! I'd suggest reading ["how to ask a good question"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Stack Overflow isn't the right forum for non-programming questions and/or feature requests. Those questions/requests are better suited for [UserVoice](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-feature-requests-and-feedback/category/160794-skype-development).

Comment: Ok I will post there too, I have created feature requests in every single place Microsoft has told me to so I'll create one there as well. If you work for Microsoft can you please possibly ask around for this functionality? I haven't heard anything from the Graph Reporting GitHub thread, Skype for Business support via our Azure EA support contract, PowerShell dev site. Not a peep. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

We don't support PSTN report in the Graph API. In UX we provide the link to PSTN report managed by Sfb team. The link is something like: https://admin1a.online.lync.com/lscp/?language=en-US&tenantID=&p=ReportsPSTNUsageDetails

Comment: That's exactly the problem. From my understanding there is no way to obtain the PSTN call logs\reports without going through the Office 365 reports GUI.

*PowerShell provided PSTN call logs but the cmdlet "no longer gives accurate results" according to this page -- https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt617040(v=exchg.160).aspx

That page states the following: "The Office 365 reporting cmdlets have been replaced by a new reporting API." We just need a way to pull PSTN call logs without a GUI just like any other VoIP provider offers.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I'll forward it to the related teams.